# ruby state_machine events getting triggered without call

Tags: ruby, rubygems, state-machine

New to ruby here, trying to make a state machine using ruby gem `state_machine`. My code is as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'state_machine'
require_relative 'decisao'
require_relative 'Update'
require_relative 'Register'

class Estado
  state_machine :state, initial: :base do
    event :decisao do
      transition :base => :decisao
      Decisao.AnalisarPlanilha()
    end

    event :update do
      transition :base => :update
      Update.AtualizarPlanilha()
    end

    event :cadastro do
      transition :base => :cadastro
      Register.ExecuteRegister()
    end

    event :visualizar do
      transition :base => :visualizar
      Report.OnVisualize()
    end

    event :retornar do
      transition any => :base
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I call for an instance of the class `Estado` to be created, it begins to go through all the events in order of appearance, regardless of me calling for any transitions. My intention here is to have a base state, that changes depending on which function of the program is needed, then an event can return us to that base state.

Comment: Do you really have a class named `Update`? I would change it something else, but a verb.

Comment: `require_relative 'Update'; require_relative 'Register'` - Lowercase names there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting confused on how to use state machines, you should be using events to transition to a different state and then do your work in before/after block for the transition, in your case it could be

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'state_machine'
require_relative 'decisao'
require_relative 'Update'
require_relative 'Register'

class Estado

  state_machine :state, initial: :base do

    event :decisao do
      transition :base => :decisao
    end

    event :update do
      transition :base => :update
    end

    event :cadastro do
      transition :base => :cadastro
    end

    event :visualizar do
      transition :base => :visualizar
    end

    event :retornar do
      transition any => :base
    end

    before_transition :base => :decisao do |estado|
      Decisao.AnalisarPlanilha()
    end

    after_transition :base => :update do |estado|
      Update.AtualizarPlanilha()
    end

    before_transition :base => :cadastro do |estado|
      Register.ExecuteRegister()
    end

    after_transition :base => :visualizar do |estado|
      Report.OnVisualize()
    end

  end

end
```

you can use `before` or `after` depending on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

The code is being executed because Ruby is an interpreted language. Basically, when the interpreter encounters the line of code, it executes it.

You have to distinguish between the state machine logic and business logic. It’s not quite clear what is superior from your explanation, but:

— whether you want methods to be called on state transitions, use callbacks:

```
after_transition on: :decisao, do: ->(*) { Decisao.AnalisarPlanilha }
```

— whether you want states to be changed from your methods, call events explicitly:

```
def Decisao.AnalisarPlanilha
  estado.decisao! # assuming estado in an instance of Estado class
end
```

*Sidenote:* there is a common ruby convention to name methods in snake case (`analisar_planilha`) not `AnalisarPlanilha` since everything started with an uppercase is treated as *a constant*.